# Vue.js + фреймворки-интерфейсы

Tags: css, style, vue.js

Используем **Vue.js** как фронтэнд проекта. Стоит ли использовать фреймворки (я не знаю как правильно их назвать) вроде **Vuetify**, **bootstrap-vue**, **Muse-ui**,  **Semantic UI** и другие подобные? И если стоит то что посоветуете?

Comment: Я не отказывался от bootstrap, просто подключаю только необходимые файлы скриптов для работы, а не весь js

Answer (score 1):

Много хорошего слышал о [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) и есть [обертка](https://github.com/CroudSupport/vue-semantic) для Vue